# TLS Handshake Timeout with kubernetes on vmware-fusion vagrant provider

Tags: kubernetes

I used the instructions in the official getting started guide (http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant.html) to get started with kubernetes on vagrant with the vmware fusion provider on OS X.

When running

```
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vagrant
curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

everything seems to work fine, but in the end i get the following error:

```
Validating minion-1
......
Waiting for each minion to be registered with cloud provider
error: couldn't read version from server: Get https://10.245.1.2/api: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I've found the following github issues:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13382
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17426

Because it seems that both do not post the question on SO as recommended, i decided to do so.

My Environment:

- OS X 10.11.1
- Vagrant 1.7.4
- VMWare Fusion 7.1.3

I'm new to Kubernetes, if you need more information i will provide them.

Comment: Seems like the 443 port is not running tls/ssl.

Comment: i still can't solve this problem. But i'm using docker now, and everything works fine.

Comment: @RomanKonz Do you have enough memory available? this might be causing it

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error - 
"Waiting for each minion to be registered with cloud provider
error: couldn't read version from server: Get https://10.245.1.2/api: net/http: TLS handshake timeout"
I just tried 
"./cluster/kube-push.sh" and this time cluster was created and validated successfully.

Environment details:

Host Machine- Ubuntu 14.04

Vagrant - 1.8.1

virtualbox - 5.0.14

kubernetes- 1.1.4

just to add, after setting up the cluster with default vm memory(1024MB) I was not able to run any pod(I tried NGNIX), it was always in pending state. So I increased the memory and restarted & now it runs fine.